# How does the Git checkout branch work?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am getting familiar with Git, which is pretty simple (I used to work with some version control systems before), but i think that either I am missing something or the Git just does not work the way I expect. One particular problem: I use SourceTree app and I created new branch (called "access") in my repository and checked in out, so it is now the working copy. But when I check the status of git via command line "git status", it tells me I am using some other branch, the one which I have been using before I created the new one ("access"). I would expect that if I change the current brach, that the change will be "local repository wide". How's this supposed to be? What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Please show us a transcript/shell log.  What you've described should work as you expect.

Comment: I am really sorry, I have noticed now that I was in two different repositories - i created one by mistake in wrong directory. Everything work now as expected. Thanks for anyones effort to help.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected, it was my fault having the same repository in two different directories by mistake.